# Unable to select/move position of attributes in Android studio resource layout file as cursor changed from arrow to hand

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

How do I revert back to arrow in order to select attribute properties?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is your problem but it's worth a shot.
You might be on "read only" mode.
To toggle between "writable" and "read only" you need to click on the lock at the bottom right of the screen Or File -> Make file writeable 
[image: Like so]